parse error while passing helm show chart to jq
Hi I am getting a parse error when i perform the following command
helm show chart https://artifactory.vvr.com/artifactory/helm-release-local/jaeger/jaeger-assembly/jaeger-assembly-1.0.0.tgz -n test | jq .

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 11

the output of helm show command is below
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: 1.0.0
dependencies:
- name: jaeger
  repository: https://dependencies.vvr.com/artifactory/helm//jaegertracing
  version: 0.44.0
description: aeger Assembly
name: jaeger-assembly
version: 1.0.0

any idea why it is showing a parse error and how can i fix so that the helm show chart output can be parsed to json as i need to retrieve the version attribute

Jq is for Json, you'll need yq

@0stone0 is right.  yq is for YAML (which is what you're wokring with)

..… or gojq …..

(Modern) YAML processors (like yq) can always process JSON data because the JSON format is a subset of the (modern) YAML format. But the other way round, a JSON processor (like jq) cannot process (non-JSON) YAML data unless it has special capabilities to do so (like gojq, which simply has both processors implemented).


jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor akin to sed,awk,grep, and friends for JSON data.

While YAML is a superset of JSON (any JSON document is also a valid YAML document), the reverse is not true. This means you cannot process generic YAML files with jq, but you need a tool that can handle YAML. One such tool is yq:

a lightweight and portable command-line YAML, JSON and XML processor. yq uses jq like syntax but works with yaml files as well as json, xml, properties, csv and tsv.

Since it uses a jq like syntax, you can simply swap the command:
helm show chart … -n test | yq .

